# Why is numeric_limits::infinity() misbehaving logically for integral types

Tags: c++, numeric-limits

`std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()` function is logically misbehaving for integral types but for double its working fine. Is there some reason for defining such behavior in standard library, which returns 0 instead of builtin_huge value in case of integral types?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>

int main() {    
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    std::cout << (9 < std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity()) << std::endl; // returns false
    std::cout << (9 > std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity()) << std::endl; // returns true

    std::cout << (9 < std::numeric_limits<long>::infinity()) << std::endl; // returns false
    std::cout << (9 > std::numeric_limits<long>::infinity()) << std::endl; // returns true

    std::cout << (9 < std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()) << std::endl; // returns true
    std::cout << (9 > std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()) << std::endl; // returns false
}
```

Comment: The standard requires `std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()` to return zero for types where  `std::numeric_limits<T>::has_infinity()` returns `false` (or `0`).   Built-in integral types (`int`, etc) typically - with real-world implementations - have  `std::numeric_limits<T>::has_infinity()` return `false`.   Notionally, a "big integer" type may be (coded to be) able to represent an infinity, but built-in types are not like that.